# PHP usort collections with varying attributes

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two identical arrays:

```
$array1 = array(
    array(
        'start' => 1,
        'value' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'start' => 8,
        'value' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'start' => 4,
        'value' => 8
    ),
    array(
        'value' => 5,
    )
);

$array2 = array(
    array(
        'start' => 1,
        'value' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'start' => 8,
        'value' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'start' => 4,
        'value' => 8
    ),
    array(
        'value' => 5,
    )
);
```

I need to merge and sort them in ascending order:

```
$array1 = array_merge($array1, $array2);

usort($array1, function($value1, $value2) {
    if (!array_key_exists('start', $value1) || !array_key_exists('start', $value2)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $value1['start'] - $value2['start'];
});
```

However, this doesn't work, and the ordering is incorrect:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 4
            [start] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 8
            [value] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1
            [value] => 10
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [value] => 5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1
            [value] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [start] => 4
            [value] => 8
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [start] => 8
            [value] => 4
        )

)
```

It should ideally place all items without a `start` attribute to the start of the array and all items with a `start` attribute following those in ascending order.

If I remove the arrays that contain no `start` attribute, it seems to work perfectly. But I need to keep those items without a `start` attribute. Is there anything I can do with my sort to go around this issue without going through the merged array, removing those that have no `start` and replacing them after the sort? Ideally I'd love to understand what is happening here to make it fail.

Comment: You're saying that anything that doesn't have a `start` entry is equal to **everything**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To place the elements without an start key at the front, you have to handle them diffrently in your compare function.

You could try something like this

```
usort($array1, function($value1, $value2) {
    if (!isset($value1['start']) && !isset($value2['start'])) {
        return 0;
    } else if (!isset($value1['start'])) {
        return -1;
    } else if (!isset($value2['start'])) {
        return 1;
    }

    return $value1['start'] - $value2['start'];
});
```